# Object doesn't transfering into function. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I need to check animal type without using operator "instanceOf". I decided to use variable animalType, and compare it with different values. But when I'm trying to run my application, I receive Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined. I cann't understand, why object isn't transfering into getType function ? Where is my mistake ?

```js
// Creating objects via constructors by prototype inheritance
function Animal (name, age, sound, region) {                    
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 this.sound = sound;
 this.region = region;
 this.say = function() { alert("My name is " + name)
                        }   
};

function Dog(name, age, sound, region) {
  this.base = Animal;
  this.base(name, age, sound, region);
  this.goAway = function () {
      alert("Dog go away");
      animalType = "dog";
  }
};

Dog.prototype = new Animal;

function Cat(name, age, sound, region) {
  this.base = Animal;
  this.base(name, age, sound, region);
  this.goAway = function () {
      alert("Cat go away");
      animalType = "cat";
  }
};

Cat.prototype = new Animal;

function Woodpecker(name, age, sound, region) {
  this.base = Animal;
  this.base(name, age, sound, region);
  this.goAway = function () {
      alert("Woody go away");
      animalType = "woodpecker";
  }
};

Woodpecker.prototype = new Animal;


// Creating objects by Object.create()
function Animal (name, age, sound, region) {                    
 this.name = name;
 this.age = age;
 this.sound = sound;
 this.region = region;
 this.say = function() { alert("My name is " + name)
                          }   
}; 

function Dog(name, age, sound, region) {
  Animal.apply(this, arguments)
  this.goAway = function () {
      alert("Dog go away");
      animalType = "dog";
  }
};
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;


function Cat(name, age, sound, region) {
  Animal.apply(this, arguments)
  this.goAway = function () {
      alert("Cat go away");
      animalType = "cat";
  }
};
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;


function Woodpecker(name, age, sound, region) {
  Animal.apply(this, arguments)
  this.goAway = function () {
      alert("Woodpecker go away");
      animalType = "woodpecker";
  }
};
Woodpecker.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Woodpecker.prototype.constructor = Woodpecker;

var Tom = new Dog("Tom");
var Murchyk = new Cat("Murchyk");
var Woody = new Woodpecker("Woody");

Tom.say();
Murchyk.say();
Woody.say();

function getType(){
 if (this.animalType == "dog")
  alert("type Dog");
  else
  alert("type other Animal")
 
};

getType().call(Tom);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
getType.call(Tom);
```

You always 'call' function without parentheses. You can check that Function class has 'call' method inside its prototype. Functions are objects (first class objects, even!) in Javascript so you treat the function as object and 'call' like using a method of an object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But now I have another question, because I'm missing something again: this.animalType always return undefined, seems like I'm not transfer object in method again. Could you help me ? What I'm missing ?

Comment: Obviously there is no object property `animalType` because you set it like `animalType = 'something'`, so you're basically setting the value to a global value which gets created implicitly. If you change `animalType = 'something'` to `this.animalType = 'something'` then your problem will be gone. In Javascript you *have to* set object properties with `this.property = value`, unlike C++ or C# where you have class members and you may, but don't have to set them with `this` keyword. Just a feature of Javascript to get used to. And don't forget `;` after method assignments inside constructor!

Answer (score 0):

Your `getType()` function is not returning a value.  In the statement `getType().call(Tom);` since getType() doesn't return anything the value is undefined.

Comment: Can i write like this:                                                                                       function getType(){
 if (this.animalType == "dog")
  alert("type Dog");
      return 'dog';
      else
  alert("type other Animal") 
};

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `getType.call(null, Tom)` instead of `getType().call(Tom)`.

Another possible way is to change `getType` to:

```
function getType(param) {
    if (param.animalType == "dog")
        alert("type Dog");
    else
        alert("type other Animal")
};
```

And then calling `getType(Tom)` which is nicer in my opinion